# Identify the image source on Apex:image tag

Tags: apex, static-resources, images, files

I have a URL with an apex:image tag like this:

```
   <apex:image value="/img/icon/mail32.png" width="15px" height="15px" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;" />
```

I am trying to find the image's location but I am unable to find. I could not find this in documents, files or static resources. When I use the URL like : https://mysalesforceinstance/img/icon/mail32.png . I can see the image showing up. Where is this image located?

Comment: That would just be a base icon then...

Comment: those are salesforce inbuilt images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce has a bunch of built-in images. While we're not technically suppose to rely on them, many of these images have been around forever and likely won't go away until Classic is no longer available (one notable exception is s.gif, which moved from /s.gif to /img/s.gif a release or two ago, in order to align that image with all the others). This [blog post](http://www.force2b.net/index.php/2010/08/salesforce-icons/) (not mine) has a list of all known classic images you can pull from. A few of them appear in the help text (like the red, yellow, green flags which are demonstrated in a formula), but many of these images have been used by developers for some time, particularly /img/loading32.gif. These images are part of the standard saleforce assets, and can be found on every instance of salesforce, including sandboxes.